# Disambiguate [scoop]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

[scoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scoop) has currently 10 questions (after I just fixed the tag in a [sqoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqoop)-related one), some related to [SCOOP (Scalable COncurrent Operations in Python)](https://github.com/soravux/scoop/) and some to [Scoop - A command-line installer for Windows](https://scoop.sh/). The original purpose of the tag is unclear, since it has no description. I propose:

1. Retag questions related to the Python library to [python-scoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-scoop).
2. Either leave those related to the installer tagged with [scoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scoop) or retag to something like [scoop-installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scoop-installer).

Comment: Are questions about the scoop-installer even on-topic on SO? Sounds more like a general installer -> off-topic (general computing hardware and software).

Comment: @BDL Yeah I know, I'm also not sure about that, but there are plenty of questions on `[chocolatey]` or `[apt]` too... I guess environment setup can be on-topic (or so it suggests the continuous stream of questions about installation problems with TensorFlow that I witness every day), but I agree it sounds more like SuperUser than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just 10 questions, so it isn't hard to do it manually.

Out of 6 questions tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), 3 were off topic. I closed them, and retagged the 3 others to [python-scoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-scoop). The remaining 4 questions were about the Scoop Installer, and I added the [scoop-installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scoop-installer) to it.

I updated the tag wikis of both the tags as well.